# pagination doesnt link to where clause when new page clicked

Tags: php, pagination, where-clause

i have a where clause that shows all categorys where the id=the input value from the previouse page. the pagination works giving me the right amount of pages and the where clause gives me the correct records.

when i click on a page nuber however the records shown on the page are not the next set of required records but all records

the link to to each page doesnt identfy the whereclause

```
<?php
include ('dbconnect.php');
$db = dbConnect();  // function defined in dbconnect.php

echo $filmCategory = isset($_REQUEST['filmCategory']) ? $_REQUEST['filmCategory'] : null;

$whereclause = "where c.category_id = '$filmCategory'";


require_once('functions.php');

//user input this will limit the amount of records per page the user can see
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$perPage = isset($_GET['per-page']) && $_GET['per-page'] <=15 ? (int)$_GET['per_page'] : 10;

//positioning: replace certain variables within the query
//this will be where the rows start from the calculation will work out if page is greater than 1
//if the page is less than one it should be 0
$start = ($page > 1) ? ($page * $perPage) - $perPage : 0;
//query to fetch required records
$filmSQL =  $db->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  f.title, f.description, f.release_year, c.name,
f.rating, f.last_update
from nfc_film f
inner join nfc_film_category fc
on f.film_id = fc.film_id
inner join nfc_category c
on fc.category_id = c.category_id
$whereclause
LIMIT {$start}, {$perPage}");

// execute the query and get the title, description, release year, name, rating and last update of film
$filmSQL->execute();

//echo the table with the titles and correct data from SQL
echo "<table border=\"1\">\n";
    echo "<tr><th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Release Year</th><th>Category</th><th>Rating</th><th>Last Update</th></tr>";

    while ($filmInfo = $filmSQL->fetchObject()) {

    $upperLower= upperFirst(lowercase($filmInfo->title));
    $uLDescription= firstUpper(lowercase($filmInfo->description));
    $noChar = substr($uLDescription,0,100).'...';
    echo "<form action='filmInfo.php' method='get'>";
        echo "<tr>
            <td><input type='text' name='filmInfo' value='{$upperLower}'</td>
            <td><p>$noChar.</p></td>
            <td>{$filmInfo->release_year}</td>
            <td>{$filmInfo->name}</td>
            <td>{$filmInfo->rating}</td>
            <td>{$filmInfo->last_update}</td>
            <td><input type='submit' value='Film Details' </td>
        </tr>";
        echo" </form>";

    }
echo "</table>";
//pages
$total = $db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total")->fetch()['total'];
$pages = ceil($total / $perPage);


?>

<div id="pagintation">
    <?php for($x = 1; $x <= $pages; $x++):  ?>
        <a href="?page=<?php echo $x; ?>"><?php echo $x; ?></a>
    <?php endfor;?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: If you're using CSS for this `<div id="pagintation">` make sure you're using the same word here. `pagintation` is mispelled. So if your CSS reads as `#pagination`, your CSS won't work for it. That's how it's spelled btw. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the category to the links:

```
$cat = isset($_REQUEST['category']) ? "&category=" . $_REQUEST['category'] : '';
?>

<div id="pagintation">
    <?php for($x = 1; $x <= $pages; $x++):  ?>
        <a href="?page=<?php echo $x . $cat; ?>"><?php echo $x; ?></a>
    <?php endfor;?>
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- That was a different problem, it wasn't showing the table at all when he clicked the page links. It was caused by the `if(isset($_POST['search']))` at the top, which he removed from this version.

Comment: Still, 95% of the code in both are identical. Good luck with this ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- And the 5% that's different was the solution to the first problem. It then uncovered a new problem.

Comment: Then, the OP/answerer should have resolved it there. I don't see the point for a new question while another hasn't been marked as solved, unless they don't know how Stack rolls ;-)

Comment: I've marked that one as a dup of this, since this has the correct original code and the solution to the second problem.